# WebAPI model binding from uri, check for wrong property names (typos)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I want to know in a Get method using [FromUri] complex model object, if some parametername not exists in the model.

So I can include in the response some kind of warning to the user to let him know that some of the querystring parameters are not valid for this endpoint.

(Currently working for [FromBody] due I can check this in the Jsonserializer)

Any idea?

**Edit:**

Let say that I have a default WebAPI project. But let me put a more clear sample.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyActionAsync(MyModel model)
```

And

```
public class MyModel
{
public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

If I make a request

```
http://localhost/myapi/myaction?PropertyOne=1&PropertyThree=3
```

I want to know what would be a generic way to get that "PropertyThree" and include a warning in the response saying that "PropertyThree not match any property in the model".

(The part to include that in the response is not the issue, I already including it if the request is POST).

I mean a "generic way" because I have a lot of endpoints and I don't want to implement a solution that has to change all the existing controllers/actions.

Comment: and what do you have? [code]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am missing something here as it is a bit hard to answer without seeing your code, but can't you check if the property is null?

```
if (MyComplexObject.MyProperty == null) {
    //send message to user
}
```